# Single question thread with multiple questions, some duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette

I've recently run into many questions where to author asks several related questions in one post, many of them asked before.

I'm wondering what out policy is on such questions:

1. Should I vote-close them as being not constructive?
2. Should I vote-close them as duplicates?
3. Should I leave them be? Or even suggest an answer?

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449066/browserless-web-scraping-of-ajax-page#15449066) - Each of the questions: Waiting for an AJAX request with selenium, and headless browsing in selenium have been asked here before, but he asked both in one.

I've done my best to search for similar questions here in meta but I was unable to find any, reading appreciated.

Comment: You have 4 questions in your question... :-)

Comment: related: [How best to ask a question that is really multiple related questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122174/how-best-to-ask-a-question-that-is-really-multiple-related-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the questions are duplicated somewhere else, add them in the comments and close as duplicate of one of them.

If one of the questions doesn't have a duplicate, I'd add the duplicates as comments and answer the question without duplicate.

Comment: I prefer this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122178/215590 which is from a question I think this one should be a duplicate of.  I think working through multiple questions within a question rather than insisting on one question per question encourages convoluted rather than clear Q&As.