# Multiple (related) questions in a question?

Tags: discussion

I've read the [How best to ask a question that is really multiple related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122174/how-best-to-ask-a-question-that-is-really-multiple-related-questions) but unfortunately, those questions were very vague. I have to post around 6 questions regarding the implementation of PHP markdown that look very briefly and crudely like this:

1. Should I store the HTML and the Markdown or just the Markdown. I am aware this has been argued ad infinitum, and I've read the arguments for and against both...
2. Does PHP Markdown offer features very similar to [Markdownsharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) or is there a significant difference between the two?
3. Which editor do I use? WMD seems to be the most common, but what is easy to set up, easy to use and will work with PHP Markdown as the backend?
4. How do I store the Markdown (and the HTML, depending on your answer to question 1) securely in a MySQL database? To prevent SQL injections, does a `mysql_real_escape_string` suffice?
5. How do I solve the problem of user input having potentially dangerous tags that could lead to XSS attacks? I will probably be using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter, will...
6. Is there already a solution for solving all these problems in one go so that I can peacefully be lazy?

The questions are certainly related, but do they belong together or do I post **6+** separate questions about the same topic? Also, if it makes sense to keep them together, what should be the convention about accepting answers? If 6 different answers each answer one point, which should I accept?

Comment: To me, numbers 1, 2 and 3 look non-constructive by SO's definitions and will get closed.  5 and 6 will probably get closed as "not a real question" by SO's standards as well.  So that leaves you with question #4.  There, I saved you some time and suffering and downvotes.

Comment: The first question might be on topic on something like [dba.SE] but I recommend reading their faq carefully before. (Think it can fit in data modelling)

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers I beg to differ. Questions similar to 1, 4 and 5 exist, but they don't answer my question. 3 and 6, agreed. As to 2, I thought (and still do think) it's a sensible question, but everybody seems to disagree. When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of those questions are closable, and putting them together just makes things worse.

- your first question is soliciting debate or opinions, and unless there's a specific concrete reason why you can't decide which way to do it, then it's **Not constructive**  The big red flag for this one is the `and I've read the arguments for and against both`
- your second question may or may not get closed, because although I can't find a specific close reason for it(it's kinda not constructive), you clearly don't have a specific and concrete problem associated with it yet.
- your third question is a shopping quesiton and will be closed
- your fourth question is okay so long as it's not a duplicate, but it could be phrased differently.  You want to make it more focused:  `How do I store [insert thing to store here] in such a way that will prevent sql injections and other security breaches`
- your fifth question is okay, but it has the XY problem `(I need to do X, and I think I can use Y)`.
- your sixth question is not even a question, It's a meta question of your other 5.

And further, by combining all of that into one question, you have just turned your collection of good and bad questions into one bad `"Here are my requirements, Do all this work for me"` question.

---

My advice would be to just ask 1 question per question, and to ask only when you have a problem that you can't otherwise solve.

Make your questions focused, simple, and concrete, and above all else, make them digestible to the future users who will find your question in google.

Comment: I certainly agree with your points in theory, but practically, I'm still not completely convinced. The first question actually exists in multiple versions, I think mine is just more specific. Question 2 is non constructive? I thought asking programmers the difference between two popular tools was a good idea.. Third, yes. Fourth, okay. Since I wrote only part of my fifth question here, it is unclear. And sixth, agreed.
I intend to ask these only because I could not solve them by research by the way. I've spent around an average of an hour on each one.
In any case, thanks.