# If my sub-question's answer is more important to me, which answer should I accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

This is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686686/how-can-i-check-foreign-key-constrain-on-delete-restrict-using-php).

I feel my sub-question's answer is best fit for me. But this question did not include my title.  I am not sure if I should accept this answer because both answer are suitable for acceptance. If I accept my title-related answer, I guess my sub question's answer is more important then my original question's answer.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is why you should not overload a question with more than one question

Comment: may be both questions are related between each other

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122174/how-best-to-ask-a-question-that-is-really-multiple-related-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's entirely up to you.  Pick the answer that helped you the most, or that you feel is the "best" answer to your question, using whatever metrics you want.

Everyone else has votes to offer their own opinion of the quality of those answers.

Also note that if people aren't interpreting your question how you intended consider editing the question to better reflect what you meant, or to emphasize what is most important to you.