# Helping a user who asks multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, multiple-questions

A brand new user asked two very unrelated questions in a single post. Both had sufficient detail to become their own post. See the revision history here:

> [Two Pokemon Questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/22782/revisions)

What is the best way to help a new user learn how to post a single question per post? I could...

- Slice the post in half and encourage the user to repost the other half as a separate question.
- Slice the post in half, post the other half myself, and leave a comment explaining what I did and why.
- Leave the post alone and encourage the user to separate his own questions.

All three methods have their downsides. I don't want to drive the new user away with aggressive editing, but I don't want to allow answerers a chance to post a double answer either, because that makes it almost impossible to split the two.

Comment: I'd edit to remove the second question then leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: @Won't That would be the first option listed.

Comment: And that's the option I'd take.

Comment: I think this question should be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122174

Comment: @PolyGeo That post has to do with asking multiple related questions in a single post. This post is just about the opposite of that. I think that gnat and Martijn Pieters did a great job identifying the post that this one is really a duplicate of.